# Handling optional parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a static javascript function that can take 1, 2 or 3 parameters:

```
function getData(id, parameters, callback) //parameters (associative array) and callback (function) are optional
```

I know I can always test if a given parameter is undefined, but how would I know if what was passed was the parameter or the callback?

What's the best way of doing this?

---

Examples of what could be passed in:

1:

```
getData('offers');
```

2:

```
var array = new Array();
array['type']='lalal';
getData('offers',array);
```

3:

```
var foo = function (){...}
getData('offers',foo);
```

4:

```
getData('offers',array,foo);
```

Comment: Can you show  an example of what could be passed in?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can know how many [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) were passed to your function and you can check if your second argument is a function or not:

```
function getData (id, parameters, callback) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) { // if only two arguments were supplied
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(parameters) == "[object Function]") {
      callback = parameters; 
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

You can also use the arguments object in this way:

```
function getData (/*id, parameters, callback*/) {
  var id = arguments[0], parameters, callback;

  if (arguments.length == 2) { // only two arguments supplied
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[1]) == "[object Function]") {
      callback = arguments[1]; // if is a function, set as 'callback'
    } else {
      parameters = arguments[1]; // if not a function, set as 'parameters'
    }
  } else if (arguments.length == 3) { // three arguments supplied
      parameters = arguments[1];
      callback = arguments[2];
  }
  //...
}
```

If you are interested, give a look to this [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/) by John Resig, about a technique to simulate method overloading on JavaScript.

Comment: Why use Object.prototype.toString.call(parameters) == "[object Function]" and not typeof(parameters) === 'function'? Is there some important difference between them? P.S. the article you mention seem to use the latter

Comment: @TomerCagan I think it is a matter of preference(ish). There are some good answers/comments on the topic under [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5999998/690912) question.

Answer (score 75):

Er - that would imply that you are invoking your function with arguments which aren't in the proper order... which I would not recommend.

I would recommend instead feeding an object to your function like so:

```
function getData( props ) {
    props = props || {};
    props.params = props.params || {};
    props.id = props.id || 1;
    props.callback = props.callback || function(){};
    alert( props.callback )
};

getData( {
    id: 3,
    callback: function(){ alert('hi'); }
} );
```

Benefits:

- you don't have to account for argument order
- you don't have to do type checking
- it's easier to define default values because no type checking is necessary
- less headaches. imagine if you added a fourth argument, you'd have to update your type checking every single time, and what if the fourth or consecutive are also functions?

Drawbacks:

- time to refactor code

If you have no choice, you could use a function to detect whether an object is indeed a function ( see last example ).

Note: This is the proper way to detect a function:

```
function isFunction(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Function]";
}

isFunction( function(){} )
```

Comment: "this would work 99% of the time due to some ES bugs."
Can you explain more? Why could it go wrong?

Comment: I added the correct code to detect a function. I believe the bug is here: http://bugs.ecmascript.org/ticket/251

Comment: I would highly suggest you feed just one object. If not, use CMS's method.

Comment: Oh... damn... Just posted the same idea.

Comment: One other possible drawback is lack of intellisense. I don't consider this a big deal, but should be noted.

Comment: Great approach in general, except perhaps when the function is very often used with some default values. Like in `getData(id)`, with exceptional need for specifying less common arguments like the callback.

Answer (score 2):

So use the `typeof` operator to determine if the second parameter is an Array or function.

This can give some suggestions:
https://planetpdf.com/testing-for-object-types-in-javascript/

I am not certain if this is work or homework, so I don't want to give you the answer at the moment, but the typeof will help you determine it.

Answer (score 2):

You should check type of received parameters. Maybe you should use `arguments` array since second parameter can sometimes be 'parameters' and sometimes 'callback' and naming it parameters might be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question, but I dealt with this recently. Let me know what you think of this solution.

I created a utility that lets me strongly type arguments and let them be optional. You basically wrap your function in a proxy. If you skip an argument, it's *undefined*. It may get quirky if you have multiple *optional* arguments with the same type right next to each other. (There are options to pass functions instead of types to do custom argument checks, as well as specifying default values for each parameter.)

This is what the implementation looks like:

```
function displayOverlay(/*message, timeout, callback*/) {
  return arrangeArgs(arguments, String, Number, Function, 
    function(message, timeout, callback) {
      /* ... your code ... */
    });
};
```

For clarity, here is what is going on:

```
function displayOverlay(/*message, timeout, callback*/) {
  //arrangeArgs is the proxy
  return arrangeArgs(
           //first pass in the original arguments
           arguments, 
           //then pass in the type for each argument
           String,  Number,  Function, 
           //lastly, pass in your function and the proxy will do the rest!
           function(message, timeout, callback) {

             //debug output of each argument to verify it's working
             console.log("message", message, "timeout", timeout, "callback", callback);

             /* ... your code ... */

           }
         );
};
```

You can view the arrangeArgs proxy code in my GitHub repository here:

https://github.com/joelvh/Sysmo.js/blob/master/sysmo.js

Here is the utility function with some comments copied from the repository:

```
/*
 ****** Overview ******
 * 
 * Strongly type a function's arguments to allow for any arguments to be optional.
 * 
 * Other resources:
 * http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/
 * 
 ****** Example implementation ******
 * 
 * //all args are optional... will display overlay with default settings
 * var displayOverlay = function() {
 *   return Sysmo.optionalArgs(arguments, 
 *            String, [Number, false, 0], Function, 
 *            function(message, timeout, callback) {
 *              var overlay = new Overlay(message);
 *              overlay.timeout = timeout;
 *              overlay.display({onDisplayed: callback});
 *            });
 * }
 * 
 ****** Example function call ******
 * 
 * //the window.alert() function is the callback, message and timeout are not defined.
 * displayOverlay(alert);
 * 
 * //displays the overlay after 500 miliseconds, then alerts... message is not defined.
 * displayOverlay(500, alert);
 * 
 ****** Setup ******
 * 
 * arguments = the original arguments to the function defined in your javascript API.
 * config = describe the argument type
 *  - Class - specify the type (e.g. String, Number, Function, Array) 
 *  - [Class/function, boolean, default] - pass an array where the first value is a class or a function...
 *                                         The "boolean" indicates if the first value should be treated as a function.
 *                                         The "default" is an optional default value to use instead of undefined.
 * 
 */
arrangeArgs: function (/* arguments, config1 [, config2] , callback */) {
  //config format: [String, false, ''], [Number, false, 0], [Function, false, function(){}]
  //config doesn't need a default value.
  //config can also be classes instead of an array if not required and no default value.

  var configs = Sysmo.makeArray(arguments),
      values = Sysmo.makeArray(configs.shift()),
      callback = configs.pop(),
      args = [],
      done = function() {
        //add the proper number of arguments before adding remaining values
        if (!args.length) {
          args = Array(configs.length);
        }
        //fire callback with args and remaining values concatenated
        return callback.apply(null, args.concat(values));
      };

  //if there are not values to process, just fire callback
  if (!values.length) {
    return done();
  }

  //loop through configs to create more easily readable objects
  for (var i = 0; i < configs.length; i++) {

    var config = configs[i];

    //make sure there's a value
    if (values.length) {

      //type or validator function
      var fn = config[0] || config,
          //if config[1] is true, use fn as validator, 
          //otherwise create a validator from a closure to preserve fn for later use
          validate = (config[1]) ? fn : function(value) {
            return value.constructor === fn;
          };

      //see if arg value matches config
      if (validate(values[0])) {
        args.push(values.shift());
        continue;
      }
    }

    //add a default value if there is no value in the original args
    //or if the type didn't match
    args.push(config[2]);
  }

  return done();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [ArgueJS](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJs).

You can just type your function this way:

```
function getData(){
  arguments = __({id: String, parameters: [Object], callback: [Function]})

  // and now access your arguments by arguments.id,
  //          arguments.parameters and arguments.callback
}
```

I considered by your examples that you want your `id` parameter to be a string, right?
Now, `getData` is requiring a `String id` and is accepting the optionals `Object parameters` and `Function callback`. All the use cases you posted will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you can have calls like these:
getData(id, parameters);
getData(id, callback)?

In this case you can't obviously rely on position and you have to rely on analysing the type:
getType() and then if necessary getTypeName()

Check if the parameter in question is an array or a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [arguments object property](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/arguments.html) inside the function.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use typeof() here:

```
function f(id, parameters, callback) {
  console.log(typeof(parameters)+" "+typeof(callback));
}

f("hi", {"a":"boo"}, f); //prints "object function"
f("hi", f, {"a":"boo"}); //prints "function object"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only with function overloading (you need to check if 'parameters' parameter is 'parameters' and not 'callback'), i would recommend you don't bother about argument type and
use [**this** approach](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2009/09/25/simplifying-the-api-of-your-js-methods.aspx). The idea is simple - use literal objects to combine your parameters:

```
function getData(id, opt){
    var data = voodooMagic(id, opt.parameters);
    if (opt.callback!=undefined)
      opt.callback.call(data);
    return data;         
}

getData(5, {parameters: "1,2,3", callback: 
    function(){for (i=0;i<=1;i--)alert("FAIL!");}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This I guess may be self explanatory example:

```
function clickOn(elem /*bubble, cancelable*/) {
    var bubble =     (arguments.length > 1)  ? arguments[1] : true;
    var cancelable = (arguments.length == 3) ? arguments[2] : true;

    var cle = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    cle.initEvent("click", bubble, cancelable);
    elem.dispatchEvent(cle);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Can you override the function?  Will this not work:

```
function doSomething(id){}
function doSomething(id,parameters){}
function doSomething(id,parameters,callback){}
```

Comment: No, this won't work. You won't get any errors but Javascript will always use the latest function that you defined.

Comment: Wow.  I thought you were crazy.  I just tested it.  You are right.  My world just changed a little bit for me.  I think I have a lot of JavaScript to look at today to make sure I don't have anything like this in production.  Thanks for the comment.  I gave you a +1.