# How to set default values for parameters of a JavaScript function and call it with less parameters?

Tags: javascript

I have a function

```
function test(name)
{

}
```

I call it with `test("kanishka");`

In one case, I want to pass two parameters (`name` and `age`) to this function:

```
test("kanishka",27);
```

In PHP, I can do this by setting a default value to `age` :

```
test(name , age = NULL)
```

Is there any way in JavaScript to do this?

I tried

```
test(name , age = NULL)
```

but it gives errors.

I can declare 2 functions

```
test(name) and  test(name , age = NULL)
```

but it duplicates the code.

Or I can change my previous function call which took one parameter to two parameters, giving a  default value for `age`:

```
test("kanishka" , 0)
```

but in this case I have to find all function call and change them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling optional parameters in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529077/handling-optional-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with jQuery, it is only about JavaScript.

Comment: Regarding *I can declare 2 functions*: No, you can't JavaScript does not support function overloading. If you declare two functions with the same name, the latter will override the former.

Comment: _"I can declare 2 functions"_ - Not with the same name and scope you can't. You can give them different names. _"but it duplicates the code"_ - Not necessarily, you can put all the code in the function with both params and then the other function will simply call it with the default value for the second param. However, you don't need to do that at all, see the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just changing the definition of the function will work

```
function test(name, age)
{

}
```

All existing uses of the function will assign to `age` an `undefined` value..

Whenever you use a second parameter it will be assigned to the `age` parameter.

If you want a default value change the function to

```
function test(name, age)
{
    age = (age === undefined) ? 0 : age; // change 0 to the default value you want..
}
```

---

**Update**

There is now support for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```
function test(name, age = 0)
{
  // age will be 0 if no second parameter is provided or it is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 4):

basically you will do something like this

```
function foo(a, b)
 {
   a = typeof(a) != 'undefined' ? a : 42;
   b = typeof(b) != 'undefined' ? b : 'default_b';
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still call the method, even if you pass the wrong number of arguments. The "optional" argument will be set to undefined, which you can check for using an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `arguments` object which holds all arguments passed to a function - regardless of if they are defined or not...

```
test(name){
    var age = arguments[1] == undefined ? 0 : arguments[1]
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: What is `NULL`? It will be `undefined`.

Comment: better to check for `undefined` as if `arguments[1]` is set to `false` the check will fail

Comment: All good comments - I have edited my answer - does it look better now?

Answer (score 1):

You can either declare the function with the 2 arguments:

```
function test(name, age) {
   //...
}
test("James"); //age will be undefined
test("James", 22); //age will be 22
```

Or you could forget about the parameters altogether and use the `arguments` object:

```
function test() {
    console.log(arguments[0]);
}
```

This way you can pass in as many arguments as you like, and access them through the `arguments` object.

Comment: Or do both. (Use case: if, say, the first few parameters made sense as named parameters but the rest formed a list of similar items.)

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" way to provide default values for methods is to check whether the arguments have been supplied at the start of the method body:

```
function test(name, age)
{
  age = typeof(age) != 'undefined' ? age : NULL;
  ...
}
```

Comment: What is `NULL`? It will be `undefined`.

Comment: `NULL` is referenced in the original question. I am presuming they have defined its meaning.

Comment: I think in the question the OP has tried what works in PHP, since `NULL` is a special value in PHP. But fair enough, I see your point.