# How to pass two parameters to jsonpCallback

Tags: jquery, json

Hi Below is the code in which through ajax call in jquery i AM calling function 1:"setEmailAFriendCount" in which we are sending variable having json datatype but I want to call the same function from ajax call but need to send extra string parameter to it.

I am confused, how to send one. P

```
function getEmailAFriendCountDynamic(ArticleURL, Id) {
        alert('Hi');
        var location = ArticleURL;
        if (location.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
            location = location.substring(0, location.indexOf('?'));
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://contactimporter.mercola.com/EmailArticleCount.aspx?url=' + location,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "setEmailAFriendCount"
        });
    }
Function 1:

function setEmailAFriendCount(json) {
        $('#MyTextbox').text(json.count);
    }
Function 2:
    function setEmailAFriendCount(json,emailtofrdclientid) {
        $('#' + emailtofrdclientid + '').text(" : " + json.count);
    }
```

Comment: what is `emailtofrdclientid`? Are you trying to send that too from server?

Comment: send it using `data:` attribute

Comment: do you mean that you want to send two arguments to `setEmailAFriendCount` instead of just the json ?

Comment: If you're asking about overloading methods in javascript, all JS parameters are essentially optional, so if you define setEmailAFriendCount as a 2-parameter function, you can still call it with just one parameter - the second will just appear to be undefined. Whether it's a good idea is another question. See this post for more ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529077/handling-optional-parameters-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

the callback params are created in the server-side. if you want to return more then one param return a **json** object with as many params as you need. the return should get that object and parse it correctly. 
in order to send a multi params to the server send a json object and pass it under the `data` property.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "[GET/POST]",
  url: "[your url]",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }, //your object here
  success: function(data) {
    //parse your json return data here
  }
});
```

more info about [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getEmailAFriendCountDynamic(ArticleURL, Id) {
        alert('Hi');
        var location = ArticleURL,
            self = this;
        if (location.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
            location = location.substring(0, location.indexOf('?'));
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://contactimporter.mercola.com/EmailArticleCount.aspx?url=' + location,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "setEmailAFriendCount",
            success: function(jData) {
                 self.setEmailAFriendCount(jData, Id);
              }
        });
    }

Function 1:

function setEmailAFriendCount(json) {
        $('#MyTextbox').text(json.count);
    }
Function 2:
    function setEmailAFriendCount(json,emailtofrdclientid) {
        $('#' + emailtofrdclientid + '').text(" : " + json.count);
    }
```

I think this code is what you looking for...