# Shorthand to declare JavaScript variables / defaults?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two methods... one is basically an overload or convenience of the second.  How can I easily default all of the required parameters of the convenience method?

For example, the main method is:

```
var doIt = function (item, varA, varB, varC, varD, callback) {
  // Lots of cool stuff in here... trust me.  ;-)
};
```

I would like my convenience method to pass in null values for the 'var' parameters:

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  return doIt(item, null, null, null, null, callback);
};
```

However, I do NOT like using unnamed values.

I would like do something like:

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  var varA = varB = varC = varD = null;
  return doIt(item, varA, varB, varC, varD, callback);
};
```

... but WebStorm has taught me that this is a no-no.  So, I am currently doing this:

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  var varA = null,
      varB = null,
      varC = null,
      varD = null;
  return doIt(item, varA, varB, varC, varD, callback);
};
```

Which is fine, but it takes longer to type.  And, when you're writing a ton of code, this becomes more tedious.

Sorry for the newbie question.  Thanks, in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling optional parameters in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529077/handling-optional-parameters-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe change `doIt()` to accept an object with properties so you don't have to fill in property names you don't want to pass.

Comment: @jfriend00 beat me to the comment. An object is your friend in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest restructuring `doIt()` to accept an object with optional properties rather than a long list of optional arguments.  This is a recommended design pattern when lot of arguments are optional and it also makes it easier to pass along a bunch of options.  And, it gives you named options.  Then you can pass only the properties you want to pass without a lot of extra code.

```
var doIt = function (item, options, callback) {
  // Lots of cool stuff in here... trust me.  ;-)
  if (options.opt1) {
     // ...
  }
};

var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  return doIt(item, {}, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set optional parameters in ESCMA6 like this:

```
function doIt(varA = null) {
  // Bunnies
}
```

But until that has been fully implemented I guess you could pass an array instead which you can loop over in order to make it less tedious:

```
function doIt(item, myArray, callback) {

  var length = myArray.length,
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = null;
  }
}
```

Or another option as mentioned in the comments is to pass in an object.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I do NOT like using unnamed values.

Why not? They are meaningless. Why should they not be unnamed?

> .. but WebStorm has taught me that this is a no-no

WebStorm is correctly complaining that that syntax (`var x = y = null`) is defining a global variable.

There should be no problem with

```
var varA, varB, varC, varD;
return doIt(item, varA, varB, varC, varD, callback);
```

But what's the point? Personally, I think typing the nulls expresses perfectly what you are doing, and don't find typing all of them **that** tedious. If it **really** is getting on your nerves, then you could consider this:

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  return doIt.apply(null, [item, , , , callback]);
};
```

or in ES6

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  return doIt(...[item, , , , callback]);
};
```

It would be nice if JS supported "empty" parameters, as ion

```
doIt(item, , , , callback)
```

but it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Using unnamed values is the best way to go. It's less code, more clear and more efficient. I would highly suggest just using the null values as in your example:

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  return doIt(item, null, null, null, null, callback);
};
```

Also, I suppose you mean

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
  var varA = null,
      varB = null,
      varC = null,
      varD = null;
  return doIt(item, varA, varB, varC, varD, callback);
};
```

rather than

```
var doItNow = function (item, callback) {
      var varA = null,
          varB = null,
          varC = null,
          varD = null;
      return doIt(item, null, null, null, null, callback); <-- Not using variables
    };
```

Comment: That first code example is creating implicit global variables for `varB`, `varC` and so on.  It is not recommended.

Comment: So, now your answer is to just tell the OP to use the structure that they said they didn't want to use?

Comment: Well, there is really no reason not to use it, the way I see it.